# Embedding .avi in JavaHelp?

Tags: java, netbeans, avi, javahelp

I'm creating some help content for an application (built on NetBeans), and thought it would be useful in some cases to be able do show a tutorial video within the JavaHelp or have a link to open a video.

I'd imagine it would be possible using the `<OBJECT>` tag perhaps, but I don't know which object to embed. What little I know of JavaHelp I've gotten from  http://download.java.net/javadesktop/javahelp/jhug.pdf, and from that I conclude that I should get some Lightweight Java Component capable of playing a .avi and embed it with the `<object>` tag. Or rather have a link in the help that opens the .avi in a seperate window.

Does anyone have any pointers on how this is done?

Edit:

I've tried some more on adding a lightweight component of my own, but to no success. So I wonder if I'm placing the component in the wrong place. If i try to add a JButton to the JavaHelp with

```
 <object 
     classid="java:javax.swing.JButton">
 </object>
```

it appears in the JavaHelp just fine.

if I try a button of my own, like

```
 <object 
     classid="java:my.module.TestButton">
 </object>
```

I just get a couple of red "???"

The class TestBytton is just

```
package my.module;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class TestButton extends JButton{

}
```

The TestButton lies in the same NetBeans project as the javahelp-html, and the package the TestButton lies in is public. Any ideas?

Edit2: 
Ok, so i've looked into this some more. It seems that eventually the class `com.sun.java.help.impl.CustomKit$CustomDocument` will try to do a

```
getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("my.module.TestButton")
```

And that will result in a ClassNotFoundException. That might be if i understood it correctly because the classloader that will be used will only find classes that are in the 
netbeans module called `JavaHelp Integration`. And among those are not `my.module.TestButton`. So... I'm stuck once more. I don't think i can add anything to that module easily.

.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any way to embed video in JavaHelp this way. But you should be able to create a regular hyperlink to an HTML file embedding the video (in some manner), for use from an external browser. http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-javahelp/org/netbeans/api/javahelp/doc-files/api.html#external-links shows how to make the links.

If you want this to work offline, include the HTML in your NBM fileset and use the nbinst URL protocol; for example, if in `release/docs/helpvid.html` in sources (for an Ant-based NBM project), `nbinst://my.module.code.name.base/docs/helpvid.html` should link to it in the app's installation. As far as I know the JavaHelp module's link handler will convert the URL to an equivalent `file`-protocol URL before passing it to the configured web browser (defaulting to `Desktop.browse` on JDK 6+).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer, but linking to some YouTube videos often is enought. And you get high quality videos without having to deploy them in the installer.

Comment: Yes that could have been a sufficient solution, but unfortunately most of the computers that will use the application wont have internet access :-/ Thanks anyway!